# How to add json to the body of an http post in java

Tags: java, android, json, httpclient, http-post

I'm trying to post some JSON data in java for an Android app I'm working on. Is the below valid or do I need to push the JSON string in a different way?

```
HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://test.localhost");
httpost.setEntity(new StringEntity("{\"filters\":true}"));
httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
//... other java code to execute the apache httpclient
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should set the `Content-Type` header to `"application/json"`. Everything else looks good.